# Name patterns to use in query methods

Tags: php, design-patterns

I would like to receive suggestions from the community about this question:

**What's a good pattern to use to name query methods in PHP?**

Examples below:

```
// I want to get the users count from Users Table. Should I use this name?  
public function getCountUsers()  
{  
  //code here
}  

// I want to get all users from Users Table. Should I use this name?  
public function getAllUsers()  
{  
  //code here
}
```

If you guys have a great idea or good experiences naming query methods, I would appreciate to receive some tips about it!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track with your examples above, and are meeting [PSR-2 standards](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#4-3-methods), by using camel case and putting the opening brace on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

method names are depend context of class or on what the class does.
so in your case usersCount() and users() would be enough